# Custom Color for Captcha

Tags: php, web, captcha

Well , first of all i need to tell you i'm noob with this .
I found a php file that generate captcha .
It worked but the background was always orange and the text was black . 
Example Captcha : "3ab6de" . All I want to do is change the background color to another color and  to have the text with different colors ( 3ab in red , 6de in blue)  . 
I tried but fail please help  me  guys ! 
This is the code:

```
    <?php
    session_start();
    $random_alpha = md5(rand());
    $captcha_code = substr($random_alpha, 0, 6);
    $_SESSION["captcha_code"] = $captcha_code;
    $target_layer = imagecreatetruecolor(70,30);
    $captcha_background = imagecolorallocate($target_layer, 255, 160, 119);
    imagefill($target_layer,0,0,$captcha_background);
    $captcha_text_color = imagecolorallocate($target_layer, 0, 0, 0);
    imagestring($target_layer, 5, 5, 5, $captcha_code, $captcha_text_color);
    header("Content-type: image/jpeg");
    imagejpeg($target_layer);
    ?>
```

Thanks !

Comment: Sorry i was editing the original php file i downloaded from the Internet ( not the file in my project ) . My question can be closed now . Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

I think should you split your captcha string to two difference, some like this.

```
<?php
session_start();
$random_alpha = md5(rand());
$captcha_code = substr($random_alpha, 0, 6);
$_SESSION["captcha_code"] = $captcha_code;
$leng1 = count($captcha_code)/2;


$captcha_code1 = substr($captcha_code, $leng1);
$captcha_code2 = substr($captcha_code,- count($captcha_code) + $leng1);



$target_layer = imagecreatetruecolor(70,30);
$captcha_background = imagecolorallocate($target_layer, 255, 160, 119);
imagefill($target_layer,0,0,$captcha_background);
$captcha_text_color1 = imagecolorallocate($target_layer, 0, 0, 0);
$captcha_text_color2 = imagecolorallocate($target_layer, 0, 0, 0);

imagestring($target_layer, 5, 5, 5, $captcha_code1, $captcha_text_color);
imagestring($target_layer, 5, 5, 5, $captcha_code2, $captcha_text_color2);


header("Content-type: image/jpeg");
imagejpeg($target_layer);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try captcha.com library, there are several examples at https://captcha.com/captcha-examples.html

[image]

I hope this may help you.